# KML imports as a polygon without keeping any attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am **extremely** new to GIS mapping.

I'm doing RF mapping with QGIS 2.18.9, and whenever I try to import a KML (which views just fine in Google Earth as an RF signal and tower), importing the polygon just shows up as a block. I've tried looking on this site and others, but nothing suggested seems to help.

Here's what I start with (a KMZ in Google Earth):

[image]

The steps I do are:

- Create KMZ with CloudRF
- Download as KML
- Import to QGIS by Layer>Add Layer>Add Vector Layer (Type: File, Encoding: System, Source: Sample_GoogleEarth_KML_Name
- Select vector layers to add (Geometry type: point and polygon)

And this is the output I get (in QGIS):

[image]

How do I properly import the KML so it keeps the RF shape/etc without becoming a solid block with no attributes?

---

I was actually able to get it configured and it showed up! CloudRF was finally able to export as an accurate SHP file, so I had the attributes I needed and it worked perfectly.

Comment: looks like the Signal is a raster is that embedded in the KML? you might need to to unzip the kmz and read the KML (in a text editor) and docs folder to see the link of the raster. can you give a link to the kmz?

Comment: I'm not at my laptop right now, but I'll try unzipping and reading it; if that doesn't work I'll link the KMZ.

Comment: If the signal layer is a raster, you'll want to import it as a raster, not as a vector.  Layer>Add Layer>Add Raster Layer